# Constructing a matrix of solutions using findroot

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve the following equation numerically:

```
 Sinh[y]-(y+Tanh[x])Cosh[y]-y Sech[x]^2==0
```

I would like to do it by creating a list of x values:

```
xList = Array[# &, 10000, {-5, 5}];
```

and then find the root of v(x) for every x and store it in a list as well.

```
FindRoot[Sinh[y]-(y+Tanh[x])Cosh[y]-y Sech[x]^2==0,{v,vp}];
```

any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to solve your equation only, just do it with FindInstance:

```
f = Sinh[y] - (y + Tanh[x]) Cosh[y] - y Sech[x]^2;
FindInstance[f == 0, {x, y}, Reals]

{{x -> 0, y -> 0}}
```

**Addendum**

If you want to plot the Contour-Line F(x ,y(x)):

```
xContour = Range[-5, 5, 0.1];
yContour = 
  y /. FindInstance[(Sinh[y] - (y + Tanh[#]) Cosh[y] - y Sech[#]^2) == 0, {y}, Reals] & /@ xContour // N // Flatten;
ListLinePlot[Thread@{xContour, yContour}]
```

[image]

This can be done also with Mathematicas `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[f == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Each point of the contour is a solution of the equation.

Answer (score 4):

We wish to find $y(x)$ such that $f(x,y(x)) = 0$.  We know that $f(0,0) = 0$;  thus, $y(0) = 0$.  We also know that if $f(x,y(x)) = 0$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(x,y(x)) = 0
$$
as well.  Thus, we can replace the condition $f(x,y(x)) = 0$ with the conditions
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(x,y(x)) = 0, \qquad y(0) = 0.
$$
These two equations are a first-order differential equation in $y(x)$, and an "initial condition" for $y(x)$.  It's still not exactly soluble, but `NDSolve` can handle it numerically and return an `InterpolatingFunction` solution.  You can then feed your desired values of `x` into the `InterpolatingFunction` using `Map` to get a corresponding table of $y$-values.

Implemented:

```
f[x_, y_] = Sinh[y] - (y + Tanh[x]) Cosh[y] - y Sech[x]^2;
soln = NDSolve[{y[0] == 0, D[f[x, y[x]], x] == 0}, y, {x, -5, 5}];
xList = Array[# &, 10000, {-5, 5}];
yList = First[y /. soln] /@ xList
```

This method has the advantage of not calling a numerical root-finder such as `FindRoot` or `Solve` 10,000 times, and so is pretty fast.   On my machine, I get a result within about 40 milliseconds.

If you want to plot it, you can do that too:

```
Plot[y[x] /. soln, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Note that this method relies on three facts:

1. there was only one connected contour of $f(x,y) = 0$,
2. it led to a well-defined function $y(x)$, as opposed to multiple $y$-values corresponding to a single $x$, and
3. we knew a point that it passed through, namely $(0,0)$.

If you picked another $f$ you might not have such luck.  Condition 3 would be easy enough to relax (a `FindInstance` call would probably give you a starting point for your initial conditions), but Conditions 1 and 2 would be harder to get around.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the solutions for 50 zeros

```
fun = Sinh[y] - (y + Tanh[x]) Cosh[y] - y Sech[x]^2;

xlist = Array[# &, 50, {-5, 5}];

sol = NSolve[fun /. x :> #, {y}, Reals][[1, 1, 2]] & /@ xlist;

zero = Transpose[{sol, Array[0 &, Length@sol]}];

Plot[Evaluate@Table[fun, {x, {xList}}], {y, -2.5, 2.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large, Point@zero},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}},
 PlotStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
soln = ({N[#], y} /. FindRoot[
       Sinh[y] - (y + Tanh[#]) Cosh[y] - y Sech[#]^2 == 0,
       {y, -Sign[#]},
       WorkingPrecision -> 20]) & /@
   Range[-5, 5, 1/1000];
```

Looking at several examples

```
soln[[4995 ;; 5005]]

(*  {{-0.006, 0.0060001800011014146423}, {-0.005,0.0050001041671093232710}, 
  {-0.004, 0.0040000533334783891518}, {-0.003, 0.0030000225000344235520}, 
  {-0.002, 0.0020000066666711999153}, {-0.001, 0.0010000008333334749993}, 
  {0., 0}, 
  {0.001, -0.0010000008333334749993}, {0.002, -0.0020000066666711999153}, 
  {0.003, -0.0030000225000344235520}, {0.004, -0.0040000533334783891518}}  *)

ListPlot[soln]
```

[image]